# Catastrophic Error trying to use com4j to add artwork from file to iTunes IITrack object

Tags: java, com, itunes, com4j

Using Com4j with iTunes, no problem adding various text values to a IITrack object but if I try and add artwork with

```
if(iTunesTrack.artwork().count()==0)
{
  String path = new File(new File(song.getFilename()).getParent(),"folder.jpg").getPath();
  if(Files.exists(Paths.get(path)))
  {
      iTunesTrack.addArtworkFromFile(path);
  }
}
```

it fails with

> 11/05/2017 18.24.56:BST:com.jthink.songkong.ituneshelper.WindowsUpdateItunesWithChanges:updateITunesLibTrackFromSong:SEVERE: Unable to update ItunesTrack C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\TestMusic\WAV\Music\Choir of Trinity College\Carols From Trinity\27 - In Dulci Jubilo (organ solo).wav:8000ffff Catastrophic failure : Catastrophic failure
>       com4j.ComException: 8000ffff Catastrophic failure : Catastrophic failure : .\invoke.cpp:517
>           at com4j.Wrapper.invoke(Wrapper.java:187)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.addArtworkFromFile(Unknown Source)
>           at com.jthink.songkong.ituneshelper.WindowsUpdateItunesWithChanges.updateITunesLibTrackFromSong(WindowsUpdateItunesWithChanges.java:611)
>           at com.jthink.songkong.ituneshelper.WindowsUpdateItunesWithChanges.addEditedTrack(WindowsUpdateItunesWithChanges.java:646)
>           at com.jthink.songkong.ituneshelper.WindowsUpdateItunesWithChanges.analyseFiles(WindowsUpdateItunesWithChanges.java:277)
>           at com.jthink.songkong.ituneshelper.WindowsUpdateItunesWithChanges.updateItunes(WindowsUpdateItunesWithChanges.java:180)
>           at com.jthink.songkong.ituneshelper.UpdateItunesWithChanges.call(UpdateItunesWithChanges.java:182)
>           at com.jthink.songkong.ituneshelper.UpdateItunesWithChanges.call(UpdateItunesWithChanges.java:32)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>       Caused by: com4j.ComException: 8000ffff Catastrophic failure : Catastrophic failure : .\invoke.cpp:517
>           at com4j.Native.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com4j.StandardComMethod.invoke(StandardComMethod.java:35)
>           at com4j.Wrapper$InvocationThunk.call(Wrapper.java:356)
>           at com4j.Task.invoke(Task.java:50)
>           at com4j.ComThread.run0(ComThread.java:172)
>           at com4j.ComThread.run(ComThread.java:153)

The COM4j interfaces were built from my version of iTunes so they exist, I don't know if I am doing anything wrong or if its broken, I ve had tried on a number of jpogs all with the same result. I check the files exist and indeed the error is different if try to add a nonexistent file.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a path problem? are you using an absolute path? It seems to work ok for this guy here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3167465?tstart=0 (C# also uses the COM iTunes library, and E_FAIL return code is "catastrophic failure").

Comment: Well yes I think so String path = new File(new File(song.getFilename()).getParent(),"folder.jpg").getPath();

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java so I'm not sure, but this is a standard cause of problems on the COM side.